# Batch Xcopy by Name using the first seven characters only

Tags: batch-file, filenames, naming, xcopy

I have pieced together this code to complete this function, but I'm needing help adjusting the code to find the file in the source and moving it into the destination folder using filename first seven characters only. The below code works but I still find myself having to rename files with a . or - or _ after the first seven digits to corresponding with the destination folder naming structure.

```
SET "sourcedir=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\FSR2WIP TOOL\source"
SET "destdir=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\FSR2WIP TOOL\wip\"
FOR /f "delims=" %%I IN ( 
'dir /b /ad "%destdir%" '
) DO (
FOR /f "tokens=1delims=._- " %%s IN ("%%~I") DO (
IF EXIST "%sourcedir%\*" xcopy "%sourcedir%\%%s*" "%destdir%\%%I\Service Reports\"
)
```

Comment: Take a look at [sub-string expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)…

Comment: …and either delayed expansion or the `call` command. _I'd also advise that you only ever include a path separator at the end of a path, when it is absolutely necessary, in this case it isn't, (after all you're not separating it from anything)!_

Comment: @Compo, I do not understand your reasoning regarding trailing backslash. Where `xcopy *.txt nonexistent` will yield a prompt asking whether `nonexistent` is a file or directory, `xcopy *.txt noneexistent\` disambiguates the target name.

Comment: @DeMoNIoK1, your problem statement isn't very clear to me, what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Please read [ask], and [edit] your post to include examples of desired inputs and outputs. Trying to divine intent from a broken script is not always practical.

Comment: @jwdonahue, please see the code. The OP used `SET "destdir=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\FSR2WIP TOOL\wip\"`, and used `%destdir%` twice, once here `dir /b /ad "%destdir%"`, where it is not required, and once here, `"%destdir%\%%I\Service Reports\"`, where they've clearly suffixed it with a backslash, hence the reason, I specifically stated, "when it is absolutely necessary, in this case it isn't". The trailing backslash here, `…\Service Reports\"`, on the other hand is necessary, to ensure that, if the directory does not exist, it will be created.

Comment: In their `dir` command, if the directory does not exist @jwdonahue, the backslash will make no noticable difference, as long as the missing, but essential `2^>NUL` is added, which would subsequently prevent their `DO` command from working, which I'd suggest is the correct way in this case.